# error: SERVER does not appear in AM_CONDITIONAL

Tags: centos, centos7, lustre

I am trying to install Lustre on CentOS 7. I followed [this](http://wiki.lustre.org/Lustre_with_ZFS_Install) link. When I try to run `sh ./autogen.sh` to generate the configure script I get the above error as illustrated below.

```
[root@localhost lustre-release]# sh ./autogen.sh 
configure.ac:10: installing 'config/config.guess'
configure.ac:10: installing 'config/config.sub'
configure.ac:12: installing 'config/install-sh'
configure.ac:12: installing 'config/missing'
autoMakefile.am:127: error: SERVER does not appear in AM_CONDITIONAL
libcfs/libcfs/autoMakefile.am: installing 'config/depcomp'
```

Does anyone know how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

To build lustre from git use "autogen.sh" in the top level directory to setup the build environment:

```
$ bash autogen.sh
libcfs/libcfs/autoMakefile.am: installing 'config/depcomp'
$
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you try downloading a pre-built package from https://downloads.whamcloud.com/public/lustre/ ?  That is usually the easiest compared to building your own.

If you want to build your own Lustre code, which version of the source are you using?  The latest code is available at git.whamcloud.com.  Most users should use the LTS release (`b2_10` branch currently), but if you are doing new development you should use the `master` branch.